# How to export separate worksheets in a same excel file within a for loop in R?

Tags: r

I have some lists each including some data frames. Suppose the first list is like as:

```
df1 <- data.frame("id" = 1:2, "weight" = c(10,15), "Name" = c("ha","hu"))
df2 <- data.frame("id" = 3:4, "weight" = c(20,15), "Name" = c("hi","he"))
df3 <- data.frame("id" = 5:6, "weight" = c(10,20), "Name" = c("ho","hy"))
my_list_1 <- list(df1, df2, df3)
```

and the second one:

```
df4 <- data.frame("id" = 7:8, "weight" = c(5,6), "Name" = c("ma","mu"))
df5 <- data.frame("id" = 9:10, "weight" = c(20,12), "Name" = c("mi","me"))
df6 <- data.frame("id" = 11:12, "weight" = c(8,20), "Name" = c("mo","my"))
my_list_2 <- list(df4, df5, df6)
```

in truth, there are much more!

I want to write a `for` Loop and write within each Loop one of the `lists` to an `Excel worksheet` **with the same Name as the list**.

`Dataframes` should be placed one after other in the sheet and between any two `dataframes` there are two blank rows. I tried the following code:

```
library(openxlsx)
wb <- createWorkbook()
for (i in 1:2){
     addWorksheet(wb, paste0("my_list_",i))
     currRow <- 1
     for(j in 1:3){
          cs <- CellStyle(wb) + Font(wb, isBold=TRUE) + Border(position=c("BOTTOM", "LEFT", "TOP", "RIGHT"))
          addDataFrame(eval(parse(text=paste0("my_list_",i,"[[j]]"))),
                       sheet=paste0("my_list_",i),
                       startRow=currRow,
                       row.names=FALSE,
                       colnamesStyle=cs)
          currRow <- currRow + eval(parse(text=paste0("nrow(my_list_",i,"[[j]])"))) + 2 
     }
}
saveWorkbook(wb, file = "myfile.xlsx"))
```

but I got the error term:

```
Error in as.vector(x, "character") : 
  cannot coerce type 'environment' to vector of type 'character'
```

I will appreciate any contribution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are so close !
Look at the code bellow. I use `writeData` [(doc)](https://rdrr.io/cran/openxlsx/man/writeData.html) instead of `addDataFrame`. The arguments are closely the same.

Your data:

```
# First list
df1 <- data.frame("id" = 1:2, "weight" = c(10,15), "Name" = c("ha","hu"))
df2 <- data.frame("id" = 3:4, "weight" = c(20,15), "Name" = c("hi","he"))
df3 <- data.frame("id" = 5:6, "weight" = c(10,20), "Name" = c("ho","hy"))
my_list_1 <- list(df1, df2, df3)

# Second list
df4 <- data.frame("id" = 7:8, "weight" = c(5,6), "Name" = c("ma","mu"))
df5 <- data.frame("id" = 9:10, "weight" = c(20,12), "Name" = c("mi","me"))
df6 <- data.frame("id" = 11:12, "weight" = c(8,20), "Name" = c("mo","my"))
my_list_2 <- list(df4, df5, df6)
```

Export excel

```
# Module
library(openxlsx)

# Header style of each table in the excel file
hs1 <- createStyle(fgFill = "#DCE6F1", halign = "CENTER", textDecoration = "italic",
                   border = "Bottom")

# create workbook object
wb <- createWorkbook("Fred")

# For each list
for (i in 1:2){
  sheet <- paste0("my_list_",i)
  addWorksheet(wb, sheet)
  currRow <- 1
  for(j in 1:3){
    # Write the data frame
    writeData(wb = wb, 
              sheet = sheet,
              x = eval(parse(text=paste0("my_list_",i,"[[j]]"))),
              startRow = currRow, 
              borders="rows",
              headerStyle = hs1,
              borderStyle = "dashed",
              borderColour = "black"
             )
    # Update index
    currRow <- currRow + eval(parse(text=paste0("nrow(my_list_",i,"[[j]])"))) + 3 
  }
}

# Save file 
saveWorkbook(wb, file = "myfile.xlsx") #, overwrite = TRUE)
```

The output looks like this:

[image]